# Backup a maintenance plan or job in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have some maintenance plans in SQL Server 2014 that they do some tasks on my databases. I want to back up my plans to use them on different servers.

How can I back up or deploy them?

Comment: Jobs are stored in `MSDB`. To deploy jobs, you generate the appropriate script and run it on the target server.

Comment: where maintenance plans are located?

Comment: Maintenance plans are also stored in `MSDB` but they can't be scripted through a context menu. They are just SSIS packages though. You can create an SSIS package with your own maintenance steps and deploy it to a server. In effect, they perform the same job as agent jobs, which are easier to script

Answer (score 2):

Jobs and maintenance plans are stored in the MSDB system database. You can backup and restore jobs and plans by backing up and restoring this database.

To deploy jobs, you generate the appropriate script and run it on the target server. You can generate an existing job's script by right clicking on it and selecting `Script Job as > Create` from the context menu.

Maintenance plans can't be scripted that easily. Essentially they are SSIS packages stored in MSDB. You can create your own SSIS packages with the maintenance tasks you want and deploy them to a server.

Most DBAs though prefer jobs because they have the same capabilities as a maintenance plan and are far easier to script and deploy.

[Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/) scripts are frequently used to perform maintenance tasks like backing up multiple databases or rebuilding/reorganizing indexes automatically, using a single command. For example,

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
         @Directory = 'C:\Backup',
         @BackupType = 'FULL',
         @Compress = 'Y',
         @Verify = 'Y'
```

Will take a full backup of all user databases with compression while

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30
```

Will check all indexes and decide to rebuild or reorganize indexes based on the fragmentation level

Answer (score 0):

All these maintenance plans are created by developers or administrators by using below steps

Under Management -> Maintenance Plan wizard or Maintenance Plan

[image]

After selecting Maintenance plans by running wizard you can select what are all maintenance plans you can select as below:

[image]

By selecting respective plans if you generate it will generate SQL Jobs, You can script these SQL Jobs to take the backup also you can enable and disable these jobs based on requirement.

[image]

Comment: That is not what the OP asked. The question was how to backup jobs and maintenance plans, and how to deploy them. This answer doesn't answer any of the questions

Comment: Yep just noticing the question again.. Lets see what he is expecting from this answer... It is better to create similar jobs there in another server instead of backup and restore as many of these are SSIS packages

Comment: By the way what is OP mean?

Comment: Just what it says - how to backup the jobs and plans, and how to deploy plans.